# VBA: AutoFilter returns TRUE; For Each loop hits every other cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to run the below Sub within another Sub.

The issue I'm having is `wRange.AutoFilter(3, "")` fills all cells in wRange with `TRUE`, overwriting the data which was previously in them.

Just to see if it would work aside from the `TRUE` issue, I changed the line `If wCell = "" Then` to `If wCell = "True"` and I see that it does not delete every row, but rather *every other* row.

---

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows()

Dim wRange As Range
Dim wRange2 As Range
Dim lastrow As Integer

lastrow = Range("A7").End(xlDown).Row
Set wRange = Range("$C$7:$C$" & lastrow)
wRange = wRange.AutoFilter(3, "")

Range("$A$10000").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
If ActiveCell.Row <> 5 Then
    Set wRange2 = wRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each wCell In wRange2
        If wCell = "" Then
            wCell.EntireRow.DELETE
        End If
    Next wCell
End If
wRange = wRange.AutoFilter(3)

End Sub
```

---

Can you see why it would be doing that?

Thanks for your help.

---

**P.S.** As a side note, I originally had the sub has `Sub DeleteBlankRows(ByRef wRange)` and it didn't have a problem that I hadn't said what `wRange2` was.  Both of these `Dims` are stated in the larger Sub which this is run in, but that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Just a note that if you declare a variable in another sub and (a) it isn't a global declaration, such as saying 'Public x as integer'; and (b) it isn't passed to another sub when that other sub is called, then it isn't the "same" variable. It is poor practice to use the same name between subs for something that refers to a different item.

Comment: How are you setting the third field in an AutoFilter that only has one column as its scope?

Comment: `End(xlDown)` is notoriously bad because you might have some blanks in data.  Instead use `lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: You are deleting rows in a top-to-bottom progression. This means that as soon as you delete one row, all of the other rows change their worksheet references so you cannot simply move to the next as the next is no longer where it used to be. Always delete rows working from the bottom to the top to avoid this.

Comment: It should just be `wRange.AutoFilter 1, ""` or if the cells are actually empty, just use `Range("$C$7:$C$" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCelltypeblanks).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: What @Jeeped said. Work from the bottom up to prevent skipping rows. (Make that an **answer**!)

Comment: @Rory - If that was coupled with an `If Application.CountBlank(...)` to avoid errors, it is a better method than filtering. Suggest you flesh it out to an answer.

Comment: BTW, the reason you were populating cells with TRUE was this malformed code line: `wRange = wRange.AutoFilter(3)` . It assigns TRUE to the values in wRange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cells in question in column C are actually empty, rather than formulas returning "" for example, you could use something like this:

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows()

    Dim wRange                As Range
    Dim lastrow               As Long

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If lastrow > 7 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wRange = Range("C7:C" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not wRange Is Nothing Then wRange.EntireRow.Delete
    ElseIf lastrow = 7 Then
        If Len(Range("C7").Value) = 0 Then Rows(7).Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I've seen and used `On Error GoTo 0` before, but I don't know what `0` is.  Could you explain?

Answer (score 1):

When deleting rows individually, *always* work from the bottom to the top. The nature of a `For Each wCell In wRange2` is such that you are working from the top to the bottom.

In any event, deleting the rows in bulk would be preferred.

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows()
    Dim wRange As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long

    With ActiveSheet   '<-set this worksheet erference properly!
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        lastrow = .Range("A7").End(xlDown).Row
        Set wRange = .Range("$A$7:$C$" & lastrow)

        With wRange
            .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=""
            With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1))) Then
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With
            .AutoFilter field:=3
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

As per your sample code, I've left the autofilter active but cleared the filter.

Comment: `End(xlDown)` is notoriously bad because you might have some blanks in data. Instead use `lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: You're certainly correct; it's not my preferred method. I usually go with .CurrentRegion for filtering (there could be a blank in the last row's columns A and C but data in other columns) but I left it as the OP knows the original data and has been cautioned already.

Comment: Just making a note on the answer :-D

Comment: What does .CurrentRegion take into account?

Comment: @Tawm - The [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) is an island of data surrounding any cell. It extends in all directions until it meets the edge of the worksheet or a fully blank row or a fully blank column. It is analogous to selecting a single cell and tapping Ctrl+A once.

Comment: How could I use that for a column?  `wRange = wRange.CurrentRegion(0,1)` would select the entire column of the selected cell?

Comment: This is getting increasingly difficult to respond to properly without seeing some example of your data but if row 6 is completely blank then the current region of any cell in row 7 should reference row 7 down to the extents of the data as wide as there is data. So `.Cells(7, 3).CurrentRegion.Columns(3)` is the same as `.Cells(7, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns(3)` , e.g. column C.

Comment: Okay so I've found another area in my code where it seems (my idea of) `CurrentRegion` would work great.  I'm trying to see if there are ANY non-blank cells within the range from A7 on.  That is, A-Q and 7-inf.  I'm trying to use the line `If Range("A7").Cells(7,1).CurrentRegion.Columns(1) Is Empty Then`.  I feel like I'm giving too much information in this line; I say the column and row twice.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to check if there is any information in a cell is the IsEmpty function:

```
If IsEmpty(cell(1, 1)) = True
       wCell.EntireRow.DELETE
endif
```